# Lexmark C532 error code won't go away

Tags: laser-printer, lexmark-printer

I can't get rid of error code 84 - Yellow PC unit missing. I've just replaced all 4 photoconductors with genuine Lexmark parts and now the error code keeps appearing. I've swapped the PC units around so know it's not a faulty unit. I've followed the suggestions in the online Lexmark manuals and even called the Lexmark helpline but to no avail. any suggestions? Printer was fine until it gave me a PC unit life warning and I renewed them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Great job on swapping the PC units. Unfortunately, the problem did not go away. There must be something that's been damaged in the printer. I would strongly suggest you contact Lexmark Technical Support to further investigate the problem. Make sure you're in front of the printer when you call them for troubleshooting purposes.